# Fetching HTTP Request Data With PHP In Laravel View?

Tags: php, laravel, xmlhttprequest, fetch

I am a beginner web dev building a web application with Laravel. I want offers to be shown to users in a dashboard area that they can complete for rewards.

The thing is, I need to get the offers from an external API in JSON format. What I am doing right now is doing a JS Fetch at the top of the Dashboard blade view file and successfuly alerting the data like so:

```
<script>

    var offers;

    fetch('https://mobverify.com/api/v1/?affiliateid=71864&country=US&ctype=2')
        .then(function(response) {
            return response.json();
        })
        .then(function(myJson) {
      offers = JSON.stringify(myJson.offers);
      alert (offers);
        });

</script>
```

But where I am getting confused is further down in the file, I want to do a for each in PHP to generate a list with all the offers for the users to complete. Something kind of like this:

```
<ul>
    @foreach($offers as $offer)
      <li>{{$offer->name}}</li>
    @endforeach
</ul>
```

How can I pass that offers variable saved in the Javascript fetch to my PHP to loop through? Should I be doing this in my controller rather than right in the view? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: You are mixing the JS variables and PHP variables. The `offers` is a JS variable which can't be implemented as PHP/Blade way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using native JavaScript, it could be like the follow code:

```
<script>
var offers;
fetch('https://mobverify.com/api/v1/?affiliateid=71864&country=US&ctype=2')
    .then(function(response) {
        return response.json();
    })
    .then(function(myJson) {
        offers = myJson.offers;
        for(i=0;i<offers.length;i++) {
            var node = document.createElement("LI");
            var textnode = document.createTextNode(offers[i].name);
            node.appendChild(textnode);
            document.getElementById("ul").appendChild(node);
        }
    });

</script>

<ul id="ul">
</ul>
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

PHP is executed on the server, it generates html and js, then it is passed to client, where js can be executed. The js being executed cannot in any way influence what php rendered, because, well, it has been already rendered...

You will have to alter the loaded DOM structure with js (possibly jQuery or so).

Comment: Duh! I feel stupid now haha. Thank you for taking the time to explain this to me.